# Bonescript not recognized through automated execution

Tags: beagleboneblack

I've set up a beaglebone black with a temperature control program that works when hitting the 'run' button in the cloud9 ide. However, I've set up a .service file that should run the script automatically upon startup. The name of this script is Relays.js, and the name of the service is Relays.service.

However, it doesn't seem to want to run bonescript. Here is the error it gives me when I prompt it for the status:

```
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ systemctl status Relays.service
● Relays.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/Relays.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-10-10 12:07:05 UTC; 19min ago
  Process: 686 ExecStart=/usr/bin/Relays.sh (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 686 (code=exited, status=2)

Oct 10 12:07:04 beaglebone systemd[1]: Started Relays.service.
Oct 10 12:07:04 beaglebone Relays.sh[686]: /var/lib/cloud9/Relays/Relays.js: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
Oct 10 12:07:04 beaglebone Relays.sh[686]: /var/lib/cloud9/Relays/Relays.js: line 1: `var b = require('bonescript');'
Oct 10 12:07:05 beaglebone systemd[1]: Relays.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Oct 10 12:07:05 beaglebone systemd[1]: Relays.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 10 12:07:05 beaglebone systemd[1]: Relays.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The error pops on the first line of code which reads:

```
var b = require('bonescript');
```

Like I said, I KNOW this code works because it runs fine when executed manually, so why now does this error appear? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!